# AMD RX580 display UNCLAIMED on 16.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I have an AMD RX580 that I have been trying to get to work on my desktop. I have been able to get the device to be visible according to `lspci` but I am not able to get it to be recognised by the X server.

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GT200b [GeForce GTX 275]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:34 memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:f8000000-f9ffffff ioport:9c00(size=128) memory:fb980000-fb9fffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: e7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:cfe00000-cfffffff ioport:a000(size=256) memory:fba80000-fbabffff memory:fbac0000-fbadffff
```

The old GeForce is acting as my current card.

The relevant parts of `lspci -nnk` output are

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GT200b [GeForce GTX 275] [10de:05e6] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: CardExpert Technology GT200b [GeForce GTX 275] [10b0:0801]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_340
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:67df] (rev e7)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:22fc]
```

Clearly the AMD card is not loading kernel modules, though loading these with `modprobe` does not change the situation.

My system is 16.04, but upgraded successively since around 10.04, so there is likely to be a lot of residual cruft that is potentially blocking this. To test this, I have tried booting the machine from a 16.04.3 USB and I can see the card and the X server is able to detect it. So it clearly is working.

On the USB-booted system, I see the following.

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GT200b [GeForce GTX 275]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:31 memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:f8000000-f9ffffff ioport:9c00(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: e7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:33 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:cfe00000-cfffffff ioport:a000(size=256) memory:fba80000-fbabffff memory:fbac0000-fbadffff
```

and `lspci` shows that the `amdgpu` driver is loaded.

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GT200b [GeForce GTX 275] [10de:05e6] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: CardExpert Technology GT200b [GeForce GTX 275] [10b0:0801]
        Kernel driver in use: nouveau
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:67df] (rev e7)
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:22fc]
        Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
        Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

On the non-USB-booted system, amdgpu is installed:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep amdgpu
ii  libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64                                             2.4.76-1~ubuntu16.04.1                                amd64        Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu                                        1.1.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                                amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
```

Can anyone suggest what I should be trying to do to get the card to be recognised?

Update: I have blown away xorg, all the xserver-xorg packages and ubuntu-desktop to reinstall them. While this fixed some other issues on the system (yay!), the RX580 is still not detected by the X server.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem; try the following:

First check that the video device is unclaimed:

```
sudo lshw -c video
```

Then check to see if you have the radeon module installed:

```
find /lib/modules/`uname -r` -type f -name "*.ko" | grep radeon
```

My problem specifically was that the radeon module was not added to the autostart file:

```
less /etc/modules
```

If "radeon" does not appear there, add it in:

```
echo 'radeon' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Reboot and see if it starts.  You can check afterwards if the video device is claimed.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your post. I've just tried that and no success. The radeon module is now loaded according to lsmod, but the display is still unclaimed and lspci still shows that no kernel driver is in use.

Comment: This didn't work for me.